# I can not transform a file to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to transform a file to dictionary but having error.

```
def txt_to_dict():
    dict = {}
    with open("GEO_human.gaf") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split(":")
            dict[(key)] = val
        print dict
txt_to_dict()
```

This is my error

> (key, val) = line.split(":") ValueError: need more than 1 value to
>   unpack

[GEO_human.gaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLkjU.jpg)

Comment: If you save your file something like this f.write(json.dumps(your_dict)). To open and read: with open("your_file") as f:    d = json.load(f)

Comment: Are you sure that every line looks like "blah:yada"?

Comment: The error is clear, your file isn't well formatted

Comment: Show the `GEO_human.gaf` content

Comment: @Colin, no it is not but as I mentioned from bottom, I am so new in python so I am not sure what should I do.

Comment: @Alderven, I added imgur link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Json library:

To save dict into file

```
with open("your_file") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(your_dict))
```

To load dict from file

```
with open("your_file") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are more than one ':' in a line.
You can try:

```
(key, val) = line.split(":", 1)
```

this code splits the line at the first ':'.

Comment: I tried but still have same problem but thanks for your help :)