# Write json into file Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to write JSON data into the file which is writing in one line as below:

```
{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}
```

My code is as follow:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
            for data in results:
                saveData = {}
                for k,v in data.items():
                    if v:
                        saveData[k] = v
                    else:
                        saveData[k] = ''
                print (json.dumps(saveData))
                file.write(json.dumps(saveData, ensure_ascii=False))
        file.close()
```

What I need it as below format:

```
{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}
{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}
```

I tried several ways from the various answer from StackOverflow, however, I am unable to get it? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Use json.dump()?

Comment: What is the difference between your first and last example outputs?

Comment: You want to write a json object per line?

Comment: @DirtyBit getting error `Error while writing data into file: <class 'TypeError'>
`

Comment: Duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420295/i-can-not-transform-a-file-to-a-dictionary-in-python/55420357#55420357

Comment: You dont have to break the `results` like that.

Comment: So you're asking how to add a `file.write('\n')` to your loop?

Comment: `file.write(json.dumps(saveData, ensure_ascii=False), '\n')`

Also since you are using context manager you do not need to use `file.close()`

Comment: Missing `,` in your json data?

Comment: Just a side note: you don't need to close the file if you are using `with`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your json is like:

```
yourjson = [
    {"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"},
    {"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}
]
```

then you need only to do this:

```
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as pf:
    for obj in yourjson:
        pf.write(json.dumps(obj) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `json_dump`:

```
j_data = {"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"},{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}

import json
with open('j_data_file.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(j_data, outfile,indent=4)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[
    {
        "AbandonmentDate": "",
        "Abstract": "",
        "Name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "AbandonmentDate": "",
        "Abstract": "",
        "Name": "ABC"
    }
]
```

**EDIT**:

If you really want to have the elements printed on new lines, iterate over the data:

```
j_data = {"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"},{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}

import json
with open('j_data_file.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for elem in j_data:
        json.dump(elem, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}
{"AbandonmentDate": "", "Abstract": "", "Name": "ABC"}
```

Comment: This is nothing like the output that the OP seems to want.

Comment: @quamrana Perhaps, the way it should be no? Adding an alternative with a newline separator as well.

Comment: this is pretty json, somehow in my further operations, it is not supported.

Comment: @DirtyBit Certainly this is the code I would write. I don't know why the OP wants the format they specify.

Comment: @quamrana Indeed, added the way OP wanted it as well! :)

Comment: @DirtyBit further consumer ( Hive JsonSerde) consider pretty json, each item as new item hence I need it as specified format

Comment: @DirtyBit I tried this as well however it is giving me result in one line.

Comment: @SandeepSingh The above posted code is tested, please let us know what Python version you are using. Although I doubt it matters much.

Comment: @DirtyBit I am using Python3.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191529/discussion-between-dirtybit-and-sandeep-singh).