# Python convert json file to dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My Python code version 2.7.8 is

```
#Dictionary
ST['ST010'] = 'st010', 'PUN', ['A', 'B', 'C']
ST['ST011'] = 'st011', 'POL', ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'D', 'F']
layer = ST['ST010'][0] 
key = ST['ST010'][1]
field = ST['ST010'][2]
```

Now, i want read dictionary ST form json file

How to write the json file ?
How to write code python for set dictionary ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write json into file Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591341/write-json-into-file-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) library for parsing json.